# Going from a sum to an integral

Tags: integration, summation, riemann-sum

I am struggling with this mathematical point. I never saw in class the transition from a sum to an integral. I think I have the intuition, but maybe not the general understanding of how things work.

> I was wondering how to compute the sum defined by the sequence :
>
> $$ u_{n} = a n + b $$ with $ a,b \in \mathbb R , n \in \mathbb N $.
>   There are many way to compute the sum, but I was interested in
>   computing it with an integral because when we look at this graph (the
>   function floor(x) )
>
> https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9x8wsf8hwy
>
> we see that if we integrate a constant over an interval of length 1,
>   we get the value of the constant, which here would be exactly the
>   value of our sequence !
>
> so $$ \int_n^{n+1} \left \lfloor{x}\right \rfloor  = n $$

but I'm quite unsure about my method. And more importantly, I don't really know how to generalize it.

So my question is, **could you please help me giving me methods on how you transform a sum.** I know about :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum

But those methods don't ring a bell in my mind, yet. If you could please explain how you construct (using an example perhaps?) the integral given the sum. I also don't understand why on wikipedia they are talking about "aproximation" when I was thinking about computing the true value of the sum.

I m looking to do a sort of repertoire of methods.

thank you !

Comment: I'm not sure to really understand the question... Do you mean : compute $\sum_{k=1}^n (ak+b)$ using an integral ?

Comment: yes. I want to compute a sum given the sequence. So in a general way, how do you compute $$ S_n = \sum^n u_k $$ using integrals. Let's say that $$u_{n+1} = f(u_{n})$$

Comment: I also don't understand the sense of your question. May be you could give more context ?

Comment: My idea was to understand when and how can you pass from an integral to a sum. I really don't understand what is so unclear in that :/ feel free to tell me. I'm searching for any method. I already saw posts like that where people are asking for any kind of methods.

Comment: @MarineGalantin: The only answer to your question is : it depend on the context ! Your question sounds like : When do I use Bernoulli to compute a limit ?  The answer is : It depend on the context.

Comment: I totally agree with you. I can't find the post i had in mind. My main concern is not finding every way, but to get a better understanding of the link between sums and integrals. So I'm looking for answers where I can get examples of how you transfer from one to another :) I really don't get it with wikipedia's pages

Comment: @MarineGalantin: For physicists, an integral is a sum. For mathematicians, a sum in an integral. If you are a physicist, you shouldn't have problem to see an integral as a sum. If you are a mathematician, you'll understand things better after a course of measure theory.

Comment: @user657324: I wouldn't have given a better explanation :D

Comment: Okay, that s exactly what i m taking in a month. It will be my first measyre theory course :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any simple way to compute your sum as a Riemann integral. However, if you allow to use [Riemann-Stieltjes integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral), you can compute your sum using integration by parts:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n k 
&= \sum_{k=1}^n \int_k^{k+1} \lfloor x \rfloor dx
= \int_1^{n+1} \lfloor x \rfloor dx
\\&=
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0+} \int_{1-\epsilon}^{n+1-\epsilon} \lfloor x \rfloor dx
= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0+}\left\{\bigg[\lfloor x \rfloor x\bigg]_{1-\epsilon}^{n+1-\epsilon} - \int_{1-\epsilon}^{n+1-\epsilon} x d\lfloor x \rfloor\right\}\\
&= n(n+1) - \sum_{k=1}^n k
\end{align}
$$
Rearrange the terms will give you the familiar formula:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

In general, if you have a function $f(x)$ which are continuous at positive integers, the sum of $f(x)$ over positive integers can be rewritten as a Riemann-Stieltjes integral:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n f(k) = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0+}\int_{1-\epsilon}^{n+\epsilon} f(x) d\lfloor x \rfloor$$
Sometimes integration by parts of this will offer you some insight of the asymptotic behavior of the sum. However, it seldom help one to derive an exact value.

If $f(x)$ can be extended to an entire function on the complex plane. A more power tool is [Abel-Plana formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula). Compare to [Euler-Macluarin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula), it is usually easier to nail down the
exact value of the finite part of expansion using AP- rather than EM- formula.

Same as another answer, I'm not sure this helps at all ;-p

Comment: does that mean that you usually can't use integrals to compute sums?

Comment: @MarineGalantin For most functions, you can't. There are a few exceptions. The most important ones are 1) the sum is related to the power series expansion of some function you know how to integrate 2) the function $f(x)$ can be extended to the complex plane so that you can use the tools of complex analysis.

Comment: Would you mind adding an example for the power serie?

Comment: @MarineGalantin the simplest example I can think of: $$\begin{align} 1 - \frac12 + \frac13 + \cdots
= & \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\int_0^1 x^k dx\\ = &
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x}dx = \bigg[ \log(1+x)\bigg]_0^1 = \log 2\end{align}$$